# Repetition of string variable number of times in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I need to repeat the string as many times as the given input.
this is my input `abcdefg 5`

```
s = raw_input()
p = s.split(" ")
mystr = p[0]
number = p[1]
print mystr * number
```

When I use `print mystr * 5` I get the required output but not if I use the above code.

This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "prog.py", line 9, in 
>   TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: `number = int(p[1])`

Comment: `int(number)` is probably what you want.

Comment: It means exactly what it says: you request to multiply the sequence - `mystr` - by `number`, but `number` is not actually an integer like `5` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call:

```
print mystr * 5
```

the number `5` is an *integer*.

In your code, `number` is a *string* since you have just split the input. In order to multiply the string by this as an integer, you need to explicitly convert it to one:

```
number = int(p[1])
```